# Concatenate fields on a Dissolve

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dissolve

I have a feature class that that I would like to dissolve. Upon the dissolve, I would like to concatenate a comment field, which is a text field. How can I do this? Conceptual idea below:
 [image]

Comment: What two fields are you wanting to concatenate?

Comment: I want to concatenate the "Comments" field that I dissolve together

Comment: Concatenate "Comments" with "Comments"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dissolve the GroupID only.  Then extract the centroids of the original shapes.  Then do a Spatial Join with the One to One option.  In the tool field map make sure the output of the Comment field is to a text field and adjust the Merge Rule for the Comment field to be the Join field rule and add a delimiter character.  Also expand the output length of the Comment field to the maximum you may need in the field map.  The Join rule will create a list for the Comment field just like what you have shown.  The order of the joined data will be in the order of the records in the table and may contain duplicate values if the same text occurs in more than one record.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Field calculator:

```
aList=[""]*11
def Groups(f,t):
 global aList
 small=aList[f]
 small+=t
 aList[f]=small[:]
 return small
```

Call:

```
Groups( !GroupID!, !Comments! )
```

Result:

[image]

Calculate length of  "Concatenate" in a separate field, summarise maximum per group, join it back to original:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Field calculator will not work.  The user is using the Dissolve GP. Once dissolved, your fields are only in the original FC, not the dissolved FC. You wont be able to do this.