# How do I preserve all fieldnames when merging features?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, merge

I have a featureclass of polygons with 10 fields.

```
field_names = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(inputlayer]
print (field_names)

['OBJECTID', 'WorkSiteID', 'Programme', 'NameOfWorks', 'Description', 'ContactName', 
 'ContactEmail', 'ContactPhone', 'Status', 'ProjectStartDate', 'ProjectEndDate',
 'Shape_Length', 'Shape_Area', 'projectId']`
```

Now each `projectId` has multiple `WorkSiteID`'s. In other words there are duplicate `projectId`'s.

I want to merge all the polygons with the same `projectId` into one. So when I am finished, the `WorkSiteID` is meaningless, and there are no duplicate `ProjectId`'s

```
fcMerged = '.../MyGDB.gdb/imrovedLayer'

arcpy.management.Dissolve(
                in_features=inputlayer, 
                out_feature_class=fcMerged,
                dissolve_field = ['projectId']
                )
```

But whilst the result I'm getting is a new featureclass, nicely merged... it's dropped all the other fields.

```
field_names = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fcMerged ]
print (field_names)

['OBJECTID', 'Shape', 'projectId', 'Shape_Length', 'Shape_Area']
```

How do I specify all the fields I want carried across, even if they are not part of the criteria for merging?

INPUT

```
|ProjectId |WorksiteID |Programme |NameOfWorks |Description |etc
|123       | a         |whatever  |whatever    |Whatever    |etc
|123       | b         |whatever  |whatever    |Whatever    |etc
|123       | c         |whatever  |whatever    |Whatever    |etc
|456       | a         |whatever  |whatever    |Whatever    |etc
|456       | b         |whatever  |whatever    |Whatever    |etc
|789       | a         |whatever  |whatever    |Whatever    |etc
```

OUTPUT

```
|ProjectId |Programme |NameOfWorks |Description |etc
|123       |whatever  |whatever    |Whatever    |etc
|456       |whatever  |whatever    |Whatever    |etc
|789       |whatever  |whatever    |Whatever    |etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add all the fields you want to retain in the dissolve fields parameter:,

```
arcpy.management.Dissolve(
    in_features=inputlayer, 
    out_feature_class=fcMerged,
    dissolve_field = ['projectId', 'Programme', 'NameOfWorks', 'Description']
)
```

Features with the same value combinations for the specified fields will be aggregated (dissolved) into a single feature.

E.g.

INPUT

```
|ProjectId |WorksiteID |Programme |NameOfWorks |Description |etc
|123       | a         |whatever  |whatever    |Whatever    |etc
|123       | b         |whatever  |whatever    |Whatever    |etc
|123       | c         |whatever  |whatever    |Whatever    |etc
|456       | a         |whatever  |whatever    |Whatever    |etc
|456       | b         |whatever  |whatever    |Whatever    |etc
|789       | a         |whatever  |whatever    |Whatever    |etc
```

Will give you

OUTPUT

```
|ProjectId |Programme |NameOfWorks |Description |etc
|123       |whatever  |whatever    |Whatever    |etc
|456       |whatever  |whatever    |Whatever    |etc
|789       |whatever  |whatever    |Whatever    |etc
```

BUT... the value combinations need to be identical, if not

INPUT

```
|ProjectId |WorksiteID |Programme |NameOfWorks  |Description |etc
|123       | a         |whatever  |whatever1    |Whatever1   |etc
|123       | b         |whatever  |whatever2    |Whatever2   |etc
|123       | c         |whatever  |whatever3    |Whatever3   |etc
|456       | a         |whatever  |whatever     |Whatever    |etc
|456       | b         |whatever  |whatever     |Whatever    |etc
|789       | a         |whatever  |whatever     |Whatever    |etc
```

Will give you

OUTPUT

```
|ProjectId |Programme |NameOfWorks  |Description |etc
|123       |whatever  |whatever1    |Whatever1   |etc
|123       |whatever  |whatever2    |Whatever2   |etc
|123       |whatever  |whatever3    |Whatever3   |etc
|456       |whatever  |whatever     |Whatever    |etc
|789       |whatever  |whatever     |Whatever    |etc
```

If you need to merge a many to one relationship, i.e. retain all your `WorksiteID` values, look at [this answer "Concatenate fields on a Dissolve"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/156020/2856).

If you just want to select the first or last value from other fields where there's multiple values per dissolve field/s value, use a summary statistic:

```
arcpy.management.Dissolve(
    in_features=inputlayer, 
    out_feature_class=fcMerged,
    dissolve_field = ['projectId'],
    statistics_fields=[['Programme', 'FIRST'], ['NameOfWorks', 'FIRST'], ['Description', 'FIRST']]
)
```

Comment: I had understood that the dissolve_field parameter was to direct the criteria on which the merge/dissolve would be done.....?

Comment: I tried it, but there's no change to the row count. Yes, the fields are carried across which is great, but no features have been merged or dissolved. What did it actually do?

Comment: I answered based on the example dummy data you presented. But that dummy data was not good enough. Obviously there were differences in the values for some of the 'Programme', 'NameOfWorks', 'Description' fields for each of the 'projectId''s and you either need to handle with a many->one merge or add those fields as summary fields and select the first or last value.

Comment: Thanks, that is the answer I was looking for